# Where to recruit paid participants for online Inquisit experiments?

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology, internet, software, sampling

My team and I are trying to use [Inquisit](http://www.millisecond.com/) for a reaction-time based experiment looking at attentional bias. However, with the no download policy on Mturk and CrowdFlower, we don't know a good site to recruit and pay subjects to participate in an experiment that requires a plug-in.

What's a good way or site to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain the no-download problem? Is the problem, that the data would reside on Mturk and you can't get at it? Maybe if I understood the problem, I'd have some idea.

Comment: The no-download problem is that websites such as Mturk would not allow tasks that require workers to download any sort of software or plug-in. Because Inquisit requires participants to download a plug-in, Mturk would not allow such experiment to be posted unless there are ways around it.

Comment: I see. And what region of the world should your participants come from, or what language should they speak?

Comment: If you're in the US and pay for participation, post an ad on Craigslist.org. If you need local or other country, post in a local equivalent. Pay through PayPal (you can implement automatic payment in your site, all you need is that your participants have a PayPal account and give their email address). Your sample will not be representative.

Comment: The region would be in the US, and participants would speak English. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm very interested in any answer to this question. Also see this discussion of running [longer studies on mturk](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/how-to-use-mechanical-turk-for-longer-studies-i-e-30-minutes) and in particular this question on [where to post studies online to get participants](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/where-to-post-online-psychology-studies-for-participant-recruitment)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect but has anyone found an answer to this as of yet? It seems like potentially the only other option is to resort to a Javascript or Flash based method like ScriptingRT or WebIAT which then you can use with Mturk (obvious issues there and this requires more know-how than Inquisit, and I'm not sure if they run single-category versions of the IAT).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. I'm actually basing the vote on the question being phrased such that it presumes a positive answer, when it is quite possible the answer is and will remain negative.

Comment: @AliceD Am I missing something? I only see what's Craigslist suggestion, and I think it's fair to say that online data collection is moving away from downloads and towards JS/HTML5 solutions, so I don't see an answer coming.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr - Yeah you might be right. I will leave this to others to support though, it's not my field.

Comment: I've heard good things about https://prolificacademic.co.uk  Their Terms and Conditions don't say anything about plugins, so I guess they allow it.

Comment: The same with https://www.socialsci.com/terms
So, there are a couple alternatives that may work. Hopefully someone will turn up who has some experience with this.