# How effective are online providers of paid participants for psychological experiments?

Tags: methodology

I'm looking for places to recruit participants for online experiments, and in particular, for experiments using Inquisit Web. My lab used to recruit participants through M-Turk but that's no longer an option for us.

I saw similar questions:

- [How to use Mechanical Turk for longer studies (i.e., 30 minutes+)?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/how-to-use-mechanical-turk-for-longer-studies-i-e-30-minutes?rq=1)
- [Where to post online psychology studies for participant recruitment?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/where-to-post-online-psychology-studies-for-participant-recruitment)
- [Where to recruit paid participants for online Inquisit experiments?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/where-to-recruit-paid-participants-for-online-inquisit-experiments)

While searching for a suitable platform to recruit and compensate participants online, I came across several resources:

- www.findparticipants.com
- www.socialsci.com
- www.cognilab.com  (Might not be relevant for Inquisit, as they offer their own platform for experiment construction and presentation)

How effective are these resources, or alternatives in recruiting paid participants for online psychology studies?

Comment: Welcome to cogsci.SE!  This is an interesting and perennially relevant topic, but being primarily opinion-based is a reason for closure, so you might want to edit your question to focus on more specific, fact-based questions.

Comment: I tweaked a little to try to move the question from "experiences" to something more concrete like "effectiveness". I share your interest in the question, but it might be good to define what more explicitly you want to know about such services. e.g., what proportion of participants are conscientious? Do they allow use of Inquisit or plug-in based programs? Cost effectiveness?etc.

Comment: [A user recently also mentioned SurveyComet.com and TurkPrime.com](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/9075/52). However, it sounds like they are more for online survey software and may not allow inquisit installation.